# Why the foreach adding to the List also null's?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
GameObject parent = GameObject.Find("Moving Object Parent");

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsToMove; i++)
        {
            var objectToMove = Instantiate(objectToMovePrefab, parent.transform);
            objectToMove.name = "Platfrom";

            foreach (Transform g in objectToMove.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
            {
                g.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>();

                if (g != null)
                    waypointsFollowers.Add(g.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>());
            }
        }
```

If I'm using a breakpoint on the waypointsFollowers.Add I see :

[image: Adding nulls]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't checking the right object for null.

You need to do a null check on the `g.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>()`

```cs
foreach (Transform g in objectToMove.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
{
    if (g.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>() != null)
    {
        waypointsFollowers.Add(g.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not assign `g.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>();` to a variable, rather than calling it twice?

Comment: You’re absolutely right  That is the more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Why using a loop and null check at all? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67632023/7111561) ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing `g` to `null`, which won't happen unless something go very wrong. You probably want to compare `WaypointsFollower` component to null.

```
WaypointsFollower f = g.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>();

if (f != null)
{
    waypointsFollowers.Add(f);
}
```

Comment: If `GetComponent` is an extension method that checks for `null` then  `g` could be null all day without any problems...

Answer (score 0):

As was stated before that check

```
if (g != null)
```

doesn't make much sense. This will always be the case anyway since

```
 objectToMove.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>()
```

will never return any `null` entry. You rather want to check if the `WaypointsFollower` component was found on that object.

---

There are of course multiple ways to get what you want but why not simply search for the correct component right away

```
waypointsFollowers.AddRange(objectToMove.GetComponentsInChildren<WaypointsFollower>());
```

and forget about that loop and check at all ;)

---

The better alternative to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67629849/7111561) but without using `GetComponent` twice would be

```
foreach (Transform g in objectToMove.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
{
    if (g.TryGetComponent<WaypointsFollower>(out var waypointsFollower))
    {
        waypointsFollowers.Add(waypointsFollower);
    }
}
```

but as said why even search and check all child objects if you can get those components already directly via the first solution?

---

In both cases you might want to pass in `true` as parameter to `GetComponentsInChildren` in order to also find inactive and disabled components.